# screwy formatting with rails scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

Not sure what the problem is here, but it's definitely to do with the code generated by running `rails g scaffold [model]` as I've made a few different new test projects today and the only ones that have this issue are the ones I've used scaffolding for.

Here's a [picture of my index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4crw.png). Notice that the link in the bottom left is output as `(New Logfile (/logfiles/new` and the `<td>` 'name' is in the middle of the page - also on the forms, all of the text input is mirrored - that is, when i type, it starts from the right and goes left.  What's going on?

Here's the `view` for `index`:

```
<h1>All Logfiles</h1>
<hr />

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>

<% @logfiles.each do |logfile| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= logfile.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', logfile %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_logfile_path(logfile) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', logfile, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Logfile', new_logfile_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

It's an issue related to interference between scaffolding and then using '[blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).'

I cut and pasted the contents of blueprint/screen.css into my own css file and everything was fine.